# Jenkins, How to trigger a build in "QuietDown" period

Tags: jenkins

Is there any way to trigger a build in "quite down" ?

Before restarting Jenkins, I'm executing quite mode command (http:///quietDown). 
 
Since, in quite mode new builds will not trigger, and once the executions completes, I'm going for restart.

 
But, if current builds are taking long time and in between if I want to trigger a new build then how we can trigger that build ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that. It is the very purpose of "quiet down mode" to prevent new builds from starting.